# R how to import %>% in package, when used by multiple packages

Tags: r, package, magrittr

I want to write a package, which uses for example `dplyr` and `leaflet`.

Both packages export the `%>%` operator.

Which ones should I import?

Do I have to import just one of them, both, or both plus the original `%>%` from the `magrittr` package, or just the original?

Comment: I use `usethis` for package development, which includes a function `usethis::use_pipe` for importing the pipe easily

Comment: This just imports the `magrittr` version. So thats the only one I need?

Comment: Should be, yes. Take a look at the docs for it

Comment: `dplyr` and `leaflet` just import the `magrittr` version too. This would be more complicated if you wanted to import *different* functions of the same name, but since they're all the same it doesn't much matter.